# In Jenkins, if next trigger build is in pending state then how to abort running build and start running next pending build?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In Jenkins, If one build is currently running and next one is in pending state then what should i do so that running one should get aborted and next pending one should start running and so on.

I have to do it for few projects and each project has few jobs in it, I tried to save build_number as env variable in one text file (build_number.txt) and take that number to abort previous triggered build but making build_number.txt file for each job is not looking efficient and then I have to create many build_number files for each job for every project.

Can anyone please suggest me some better approach

Thanks

Comment: Is it necessary that you need to abort? Could you not wait for them to complete? Does the job take a lot of time?

Comment: I need to abort it because if it completes (failed or success) then it will send email to user who created it and i dont want to send that email because there are chances that after some time (say 1-2 min) that same user must have updated it and started new build, thats why I just want to send emails regarding latest build and not for 1 which is aborted

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, if sending too many emails is the actual problem, you can use Poll SCM to poll once in 15 minutes or so, or even specify quiet time for a job. This will ensure that build is taken once in 15 minutes. Users should locally test before they commit. But if Jenkins itself is used for verifying the commits I don't see anything wrong in sending an email if build fails. After all, they are supposed to know that, no matter even if they fixed it in a later update intentionally or unintentionally.

But if you still want to abort a running job if there are updates, you can try the following. Lets call the job to be aborted as JOB A

1. Create another job that listens on updates same as that of the job that needs to be aborted
2. Add build step to execute groovy script
3. In the groovy script use Jenkins APIs to check if JOB A is running. If yes, again use APIs to abort the job.

Jenkins APIs are available [here](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/)